# angular 7 how to draw dynamic number of charts

Tags: angular, dynamic, chart.js

In my angular project, I am trying to draw few charts for a dashboard. I am using chart.js for plotting charts with angular 7. The problem is , I am not aware of how many charts should be plotted and the number will be decided based on a http service call. This http call is to placed to a database table. Also the charts will be live charts from live data. I am using below logic to draw charts

```
<div [hidden]="!charts" class="divchart">
  <canvas *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index" id="canvas{{i}}" >{{chart}}</canvas>
</div>
```

But this is not working for service returned data.I also prepared stackblitz for this.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/charts-sykikw-ewtcy1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Please suggest how to handle this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: use child component for this `<div *ngFor="let chart of charts"><app-child [chart]="chart"></app-child></div>` something like this

Comment: I have tried that , but didn't work.

Comment: have you move `addchart()` function in child component and provide new `id` for every instance?

Comment: yes. got the service response in parent and pass it to child component. In child component called addchart() in same way but didn't work.

Comment: The `HTML` template looks fine. The problem in your StackBlitz is that the method `AppComponent.addchart` is invoked once only since the `charts` array contains a single entry. Check and correct the code inside `AppComponent.ngOnInit`.

Comment: It still didn't work. I moved addchart call from ngAfterViewInit to ngOnInit , in service completion. It throws error now. "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer is help for creating multiple dynamic chart.

Parent:

HTML:

```
<div [hidden]="!charts" class="divchart">
  <div *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index">
    <app-child [chart]="chart" [id]="i"></app-child>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ListService } from './list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public charts = [];
  constructor(private listsrv: ListService) { }
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.charts.push('canvas0');

    this.listsrv.getPosts()
    .subscribe(
      result => {         
        for(var key in result){          
          if(result[key].id < 3){
            this.charts.push('canvas'+ result[key].id);
          }
        } 
      },
      error => {console.log(' error',error)},
      () => {
        console.log('service call completed',this.charts)    
      }
    )     
  }  
}
```

child:

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="chart">
  <canvas id="{{chart}}" width="400" height="400">{{chart}}</canvas>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() chart: any;
  @Input() id: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.addchart(this.chart);
  }

   addchart(chartid){
    console.log(chartid);
    console.log(document.getElementById(chartid));
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById(chartid);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var mychart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Cyan'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 7],
              backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
        },
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

You can also check in provided a link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dinauz

Comment: Excellent , Bravo .. This is exactly i was looking for. You made my day :-). Thanks a lot.